# Storyboard warning not shown

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In Xcode Version 7.3.1.

Storyboard warning not shown in one mac, but shows on others. What would cause it and how to fix it?

I have tried following ways, but none of them work.

1. re-open Xcode
2. Reboot Mac
3. Clear DerivedData

Warnings are all autolayout constraints issues.

Comment: What else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out what causes the warning eventually:

Earlier, I changed the “ landscape" from  w:Any h:Any to w:Regular h:Compact, which impacts the constraints.

That causes the storyboard no showing warning in mine, but in other people's mac, "landscape" setting is still w:Any h:Any, there are conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can try:

1. verify both are Xcode 7.3.1
2. send the files from each computer to one place and diff them
3. click on the red or yellow warnings, and see what constraint is at fault, and manually look on the other Mac to see if it has the same constraint.

My guess is the files aren't identical.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:
Right click your storyboard -> Open as -> Interface builder.